# Adding custom markers to a map for any user who clicks a button on website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make a webpage that has two buttons. One will add one style of marker on my google map and the other will add a different styled marker. How can this be done so that the markers stay visible to all users.

My first thought was to use a kmz layer but you are limited to a certain number of them. So, how could this been done so that if 1000 users clicked the button, there would be 1000 different markers at their respective locations all over my map?

Comment: Any ideas? I was hoping for some responses :(

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you need a webpage with 2 buttons that will add 2 differentstyled markers and you want that all users will see all this mark universe may I right?

Comment: Yes that is correct Rodrigo. Thanks for your help. If possible I have a firebase set up that I can use as well.

Comment: I would actually rather use the firebase and just plot individual markers. Any ideas?

Comment: HI Sorry for the delay in he response, so basically I think you need something a little bit more complex than a KML, what about store them in the database and then trigger an event that update the markers in the map? Is my first "draft"  Idea....

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking. I was hoping to use firebase but I am not sure how to implement firebase into the maps api. Does anyone have an idea what the code would look like for this?

Comment: Well I do not know about firebase database, but reading a little bit about it,it seems  that the firebase database update all clients, so my initial thought is that somehow you have to catch the "updates" of the firebase. If you can do that then the rest is easy, just  trigger an initialize function that would update the markers with the information you already have.